# how to efficiently code in metapost?

Tags: metapost

I am trying to get better at metapost, but the error messages are pretty cryptic (if there are at all) and it always takes a big effort go compile an mp file. Up 'best' program for writing and compiling mp so far is http://www.tlhiv.org/mppreview/. It does provide some error messages but most of them are not useful.

What program do you use for writing/debugging your metapost code?

Is there a good IDE for writing metapost (that e.g. checks syntax and automatically updates a preview)?

MP seems to be such a nice thing but it seems for beginners it is incredibly complicated to get into.

Comment: Do you get better error messages when you compile at the command line? If so, your IDE is hiding stuff from you. If not, I doubt any IDE will expand on the error messages produced by the compilation command itself.

Comment: What platform are you using? Windows? OSX? Linux?

Comment: I am using win7 with miktex (texmaker as editor for tex files)

Answer (score 3):

If you use the gmp package, you can compile your document and get the Metapost figure at the same time; so if you need an IDE, the one you use for LaTeX will do.

Myself, I have a very short shell script to compile the figure and a de minimis LaTeX file for viewing it:

```
#!/bin/sh
mpost figure.mp;
mv figure.1 figure.mps;
pdflatex testfigure.tex;
```

The file testfigure.tex is very simple, as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includegraphic{figure.mps}
\end{figure}
```

It occurs to me that I really should just have the script write out this file as well as compile it; it would be very easy, and cut out a step in preparing to develop Metapost figures.

This small preparation done, I can just go to work on the figure and compile/view it with a single command.  I write it in vim and view it in xpdf.

Good luck with Metapost; it really is a joy.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I already tried to make a batch file (successfull) to do the work, but there too I cannot get any helpful error messages which makes it a pain to find them. How do you deal with 'bugs'?

Comment: @flawr, what happens if you run the script suggested by @dgoodmaniii with an added `-debug` flag to `mpost`, so `mpost -debug figure.mp`?

Comment: As for helpful error messages, I find Metapost's error messages to be reasonably helpful already.  I've rarely had serious trouble locating errors in Metapost; the line where Metapost finally hung itself is clearly identified, and it's usually fairly straightforward to track the error backward from there.  When I can't tell, I've googled the error and always found the solution.  `-debug` may be helpful.  When you get the error, you can also hit "H", just like for a TeX error, and the system will try to give you more information.  Otherwise, the Internet may have to be your last resort.

Comment: Thank you for your hints and comments, I came up with the following solution: I have three windwos on my screen: 1.) npp for editing the source *testfile.mp* which needs to have follwong command (or it won't work): *outputtemplate:="%j.mps";*, 2.) the console for the compilation command (perhaps gonna make a nice batch file someday) with the command *mptopdf testfile.mp* 3.) the SumatraPDF viewer which automatically reloads the new pdf as soon as it has changed. But it really is a pitty that there is no 'plug and play' sort of editor, that would it make easier for beginners...